# Images are only visible the first time in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

In safari, the images in the middle section load fine the first time you opend this page
http://cacrochester.com/

If you refresh the page, the images are not visible. It seems to only be in Safari (so far on browsers that i've tested).

Anyone know why? I'm using the NivoSlider btw.

Comment: No, it's Webkit. The same occurs in Chrome (on Ubuntu 10.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try editing your css.

from this,

```
#slider {
   float: right;
   width: 610px;
}
```

to this,

```
#slider {
   float: right;
   height: 270px;
   width: 610px;
}
```